# How gRPC supports keyword stream when define a rpc protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to gRPC and protobuf.
I notice that gRPC use the keyword `stream` as the filed rule of arguments when defining a service.
But, i can't find any defination of `stream` in the [documents](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules) of Protobuf.
How gRPC can use `stream` as the filed rule?

Answer (score 1):

The `stream` concept is specific to gRPC, and is covered in the [core concepts](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/) documentation of gRPC; the short version is:

```proto
rpc Unary(RequestType) returns (ResponseType);
rpc ServerStreaming(RequestType) returns (stream ResponseType);
rpc ClientStreaming(stream RequestType) returns (ResponseType);
rpc Duplex(stream RequestType) returns (stream ResponseType);
  // nomenclature: duplex === bidirectional streaming
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As `stream` is specific to gRPC, how the argument modified by `stream` is 'translated' into regular .proto file?

Comment: @gaoyuan I don't understand the question; I've literally used the .proto syntax in my answer, so: "just like that"; if you're saying "but the .proto documentation doesn't discuss the `stream` keyword", then yes that might be a fair criticism; all I can say is "refer to the gRPC docs for that"

Comment: It's a fair question, your answer implies that gRPC is adding something on top of raw proto, but that's not true. It's just that the protobuf documentation is garbage and the only mention is in the syntax reference [here](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/proto3-spec/#service_definition).

Answer (score 0):

`stream` keyword is defined in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#service_definition .
see also https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#method .